# Calling R func from C++ without Rcpp::export

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, infinispan

I've a C++ function that calls a user defined R function:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
void listener(ClientCacheEntryCreatedEvent<int> e) {
   int key = e.getKey();
   Rcpp::Function f("addElement");
   Rcpp::NumericVector v(key);
   f(v);
};
```

I want to remove the Rcpp::export tag because I need to pass the function as an event listener to the Infinispan C++ client.

Without the Rcpp::export tag R crashes with `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Rcpp::LongjumpException'` error when `listener()` is called.

How can I change the code to make it work?

Comment: You can’t. But you can create a wrapper (annnotated with `Rcpp::export`) that you call from R, and which calls the actual C++ function that you can then also pass to Infinispan.

Comment: I do not know which package contains the `addElement` function, but you could probably find its code on github and then you could include the appropriate header that contains the function. Compile using the necessary linkers. This will avoid calling the R function entirely

Comment: @Konrad is (as usual) spot on. The `[[Rcpp::export]]` only governs that this function is callable from R under the given name.  If sounds like you want a simpler C++ to C++ interface.  But in that case many issues, threading among may get in your way.  If however you really need R inside of a C++ application, look at my [RInside](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rinside) and the _dozens_ of examples below `inst/examples/`.  And/or avoid R as @Onyambu suggests.

Comment: Thanks all for your promptly replies.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, the wrapper doesn't solve the problem since the function is called from the event system of the C++ Infinispan client
@Onyambu `addElement` it's just a placeholder, the final idea was to be able to call user function in R in reaction of Infinispan events
@DirkEddelbuettel RInside seems interesting, but in this case I would have C++ library inside a running R env.

I guess I need to go for a less general solution

Comment: @rigazilla The other way around: [RInside](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rinside) lets you have your normal C++ application (i.e. executable) but allows you to access R by having it embedded inside the C++ application.  In the grand scheme of things, especially by today's standard, the R interpreter and its REPL are not big.

Comment: thanks @DirkEddelbuettel.  
Seems there are two distinct use cases here  
1. Rcpp+Infinispan C++ for those who want to stay in R and use C++ to fetch data
2. RInside for those who want to stay in C++ and use R for stat analysis

Right?  
Final goal is to show how Infinispan and R can cooperate. I probably need two different demo.